# An exercise on the derivation of distributions: $\frac{d^m}{dx^m} \Big( H(x) \frac {x^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}\Big)$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, distribution-theory

Compute for $m \in \mathbb N \setminus \{0\}$, $ \ x \in \mathbb R$,
$$
\frac{d^m}{dx^m} \Big( H(x) \frac {x^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}\Big) \ ,
$$
where $H(x)$ is the Heaviside function.

My solution:

For the general Leibniz rule,
\begin{align}
\frac{d^m}{dx^m} \Big( H(x) \frac {x^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}\Big) &=
\sum_{k=0}^m \binom {m}{k}  \frac{d^{m-k}}{dx^{m-k}} H(x) \frac{d^k}{dx^k} \frac {x^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{m-2} \binom {m}{k}  \frac{d^{m-k}}{dx^{m-k}} H(x) \frac{d^k}{dx^k} \frac {x^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}\\& + \binom{m}{m-1} \frac{d}{dx}H(x) \frac{d^{m-1}}{dx^{m-1}} \frac {x^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}\\ &+ \binom{m}{m}H(x) \frac{d^{m}}{dx^{m}} \frac {x^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}
\end{align}
but $\frac{d}{dx} H(x) = \delta (x)$,  so
$$
=\frac{1}{(m-1)!} \Big( \ \sum_{k=0}^{m-2} \binom {m}{k}  \frac{d^{m-k-1}}{dx^{m-k-1}} \delta(x) \frac{d^k}{dx^k} x^{m-1} \ \Big) \ + \ m \, \delta(x) \ \ .
$$
I know that if $a(x) \in C^\infty(\mathbb R) $ and $u \in \mathcal D'(\mathbb R)$ then $ a \, u(\varphi) = u (a \, \varphi) \ \ \forall \ \varphi \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$. Therefore,
$$
\frac{d^{m-k-1}}{dx^{m-k-1}} \delta(\varphi) \frac{d^k}{dx^k} x^{m-1}= \frac{d^{m-k-1}}{dx^{m-k-1}} \delta(\varphi \frac{d^k}{dx^k} x^{m-1} )
$$
but $k=0,...,m-2\ $, so
$$
\frac{d^k}{dx^k} x^{m-1}= \frac{(m-1)!}{(m-k-1)!} x^{m-k-1} \ \ .
$$
I deduce that
$$
\delta(\varphi \frac{d^k}{dx^k} x^{m-1} )= \delta(\varphi \frac{(m-1)!}{(m-k-1)!} x^{m-k-1})= 0
$$
$ \forall \ \varphi \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R) \ $ and $\ \forall \ k=0,...,m-2$.

Finally, to conclude,
$$
\frac{d^m}{dx^m} \Big( H(x) \frac {x^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}\Big) = m \, \delta(x)  \  \ .
$$
Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: I think it's correct.